# Does anyone besides Qui-Gon refer to credits as "dataries"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-phantom-menace

There's an interesting exchange in *The Phantom Menace*:

[image: Qui-Gon and Watto]

> QUI-GON: I have 20,000 Republic dataries.
>
> WATTO: Republic credits?! Republic credits are no good out here. I need something more real...

Watto's response indicates that he recognizes these as credits, but as far as I know, Republic credits are only ever referred to as "credits" throughout the rest of the film series, TV series, and EU/Legends material. The only real-world meaning for "datary" that I could find is "an official of the Roman Curia who added dates to papal letters" ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datary)), so it doesn't seem to be a use of a real-world generic term for money.

**Are "dataries" ever referred to anywhere else in Star Wars, and if so, is it just a synonym for "credits"?** EU/Legends answers *will* do fine.

Comment: I would hazard a *guess* that a datary is something like a cashier's or traveler's cheque, a way of giving someone money (in this case Republic credits) without actually having to carry cash around.

Comment: Oh, so that's how it's spelled. In the film it's pronounced more like "dietaries."

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish lol imagine the possibilities. Me: Yes, of course. I'll buy that ship for 100,000 dietaries. RANDOM SHIP TRADER: WHAT?!?!?! HOW MANY DIET PACKS DO YOU THINK I NEED?!?!?!?!?!!? I AM NOT FAT! GET OUT! GET OUT! Me: Umm... RANDOM SHIP TRADER: YOU GET OUT NOW

Comment: Why does he pronounce it dah-TAIR-ees, not DAY-tar-ees?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jas Emari (in the canon novel [Star Wars: Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath)) refers to the Republic's currency as *dataries.*

> *And with it, her breath catches in her chest. **She feels like someone
>   who has dug a hole in their backyard only to find a trunk full of Old
>   Republic dataries**—a box of unexpected treasure.*

There's no real indication that it's anything other than a synonym for 'Credits'.

---

Within the Legends (EU) novels, there's a few mentions;

> ***“Precisely. We’ll have to have the aurodium converted to Republic
>   dataries, even though that will require some time.”*** Palpatine fell
>   silent for a moment, then said, “May I suggest that one of my aides
>   help you set up a special account with a bank on an outlying world
>   that won’t ask questions about the origin of the ingots. Once the
>   aurodium is safely deposited there, you’ll be able to transfer funds
>   through the InterGalactic Bank, and draw against the account in the
>   form of Republic credits.” Havac clearly liked the idea. “I know
>   you’ll put the funds to the best possible use.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Cloak of Deception](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Deception)</sup></sub>

and

> *He passed encampments of beggars, and bright-colored tents where gamblers sat and beckoned him to come inside. He saw a troop of fire-talkers, and a trio of Gamorrean guards who took turns bashing each other with a club. Weather-beaten water prospectors pushed their way to the arena, eager to gamble away what little wealth they had. Vendors sold water in small containers.
>
>   **“Only ten dataries!” one called to Boba. “Cheapest price at the arena!”**
>
>   “No thanks,” muttered Boba. His tongue felt like a rock in his mouth, swollen and dry.
>
>   He’d better earn some credits soon. Really soon.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Boba Fett - Hunted](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_Hunted)</sup></sub>